# why does a variable in javascript seem to hold the value "undefined" even when it was defined

Tags: javascript

if I run the following javascript code, the browser alerts "undefinedabc".

```
var x;
x += "abc";
alert(x);
```

To me it looked like I did define the variable x, so why does it seem to be undefined?

Comment: Don't confuse declaration with definition

Comment: Its value is "undefined" as long as you don't assign a value to it. If you use `+=` with strings, it will always take the `old` string value and append the new one to it. The `old` string value is "undefined", though.

Comment: thank you Eric, I was indeed making that mistake.

Comment: `x` the variable is defined. Its initial value is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`undefined` is the default value of any variable with no value assigned. So, `var x;` means that `a = undefined`. When you add `"abc"` to it, you're actually doing `undefined + "abc"`. Finally, `undefined` is stringifiend to `"undefined"` and then concatenated to `"abc"` and turns to `"undefinedabc"`.

In order to concat initialize the var `x`, you should assign an empty string to it (remember that JavaScript dinamically-typed):

```
var x = '';
x += "abc";
alert(x);    // "abc"
```

[This MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables) describes this behaviour.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because you pointed out to me undefined is the default value of a variable.

Answer (score 5):

```
var x = "";
x += "abc";
alert(x);
```

Try this. You are trying to add `'abc'` and `undefined` which will result to `undefinedabc`.

Answer (score 1):

First examine the behaviour of a [Variable Statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2), Specifically:

```
"Variables are initialised to undefined when created."
```

Then examine the behaviour of the [addition operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) ([compound assignment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.2) applies the behaviour of the operator corresponding to what precedes `=`).

Specifically, point 7:

```
"If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)"
```

So, since `"abc"` is a string, `x` is to be translated to a String, according to ToString.  x, as we know from above, is undefined.

Finally, examine the behaviour of the abstract operation [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8), specifically, that an undefined argument results in the string "undefined".